# elements of a pointer array unreachable when passed to a function

Tags: c++

I cannot print the values of a character array, even when I pass the array with the address of its first element:

```
vbv_packet = Packet::create(&username[0], 
    &password[0], Packet::VBV, Packet::DATA,
    bytea_from_memptr(& new_mr, car_multirecord::HEADER_SIZE +  
   (new_mr.get_count() * sizeof(car_compact_record))));
```

And in the definition function I try to print the array values like this:

```
static Packet::ptr create(const char* username, const char* password,RTCINET_COMMANDS cmd, RTCINET_COMMANDS subcmd, Packet::ptr_bytea ba)
// TODO: unsigned short command_seq, data_seq, length
{
     //Add user authentication fields, username n password here

    std::cout << "********** CREATING PACKET";
    std::cout << "sizeof username: " << strlen(username);
    std::cout << "sizeof password: " << strlen(password);

    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(username); i++)
    {
        std::cout << *(username + sizeof(char) * i);
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
    for(int j = 0; j < strlen(password); j++)
    {
            std::cout << password[j];
    }
```

needless to say, the two string are defined as:

```
const char username[] = "ARG-CO";
const char password[] = "xxxxx!";
```

where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Pointer addition takes elements, not bytes.

Comment: `&username[0]` is pretty much the same as `username`(in this case), any reason not to use `std::string`?

Comment: I mean that you can pass your string just like this `Packet::create(username, password, ...)` both arrays will decay to pointers, or you can just use `std::string` instead of C-style strings

Comment: i can use the string type, it will make everything easier, but I do not really understand why this behavior occurs.

Comment: i know, the problem is that it does not print the contents of the arrays like this:         for(int i = 0; i < strlen(username); i++)
        {
            std::cout << username[i];
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
        for(int j = 0; j < strlen(password); j++)
        {
                std::cout << password[j];
        }

Comment: That code might as well be `std::cout << username << '\n' << password;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
vbv_packet = Packet::create(username, 
    password, Packet::VBV, Packet::DATA,
    bytea_from_memptr(& new_mr, car_multirecord::HEADER_SIZE +  
   (new_mr.get_count() * sizeof(car_compact_record))));
```

Should be correct, what are you trying to achieve here:

```
for(int i = 0; i < strlen(username); i++)
    {
        std::cout << *(username + sizeof(char) * i);
    }
```

Why are you doing this `*(username + sizeof(char) * i)`, If you wanna print every character in this char array use it like this : `username[i]`

Is it printing the password correctly?

Comment: it is now, but previously, when I passed the pointer to function only with username, it was not printing the array using username[i]. but it works fine!

Comment: now I cannot convert the array to a string using :         std::string _usr(user);
        std::string _pass(passwd); why not?

Comment: You don't have to use std::string, basically because it is based on char*